# Get variables from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to get the values from this array into two variables:

- $title
- $url

for each of these inner arrays. How can I do it?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Reuters
        [1] => http://www.reuters.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => CNN
        [1] => http://www.cnn.com
    )
)
```

Comment: You should read a bit about [PHP and arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give you two arrays with your titles and urls:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    $title[] = $value[0];
    $url[] = $value[1];
}
```

Or if you want to get your values into variables:

```
$title1 = $array[0][0];
$title2 = $array[1][0];

$url1 = $array[1][0];
$url2 = $array[1][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

While Anas' answer should work, I can't see the point of separating the data, because they obviously belong together (name & url is like horse and carriage, love and Marriage...)

```
$input = array(array('CNN','http://www.cnn.com'),array('rubbish','http://www.fox.com'));
$grouped = array();
while($pair = array_shift($input))
{
    $grouped[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
echo $grouped['rubbish'];//echoes http://www.fox.com
```

Benefits of this approach?

1. The original is redundant after processing, by shifting, you're freeing up memory (the array is being broken apart). So it's more efficient.
2. Your data integrity is somewhat more guaranteed IMO (name and site stay paired).
3. You can still get all names and all urls as separate, numerically indexed arrays if you want:

---

```
$title = array_keys($grouped);
$urls = array_values($grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foearch ($yourArrayName as $innerArray){
 $title=$innerArray[0];
 $url=$innerArray[1];
 echo $title.'-'.$url;
}
```

In that way, you first iterate over outer array's elements and, then, you can get every value that you're interested in.

If you want to store all elements, you have to create a new array but, at this point, why don't "simply" mantain the original one?

Answer (score 0):

**Copy this code:**

```
$title = array();
$url = array();

foreach ($array as $value)
{
    $title[] = $value[0];
    $url[] = $value[1];
}

print_r($title);
print_r($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $titles=array();
    $urls=array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
       $titles[]=$value[$key][0];
       $urls[]=$value[$key][1];
    }
?>
```

Using this code you can make two different single dimensional array data with holding n number of your array structured data.